# Symbologies not working on older version of QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm using QGIS v3.28.1 and also I have QGIS 3.16 already installed on my PC, when I recently used 3.28 and did some work on it then opened the same file in QGIS 3.16 all the symbologies were missing so I needed to copy symbology style from 3.28 QGIS and paste it in 3.16, so how can I avoid this copy and paste and make it work fine?

Answer (score 0):

Did you used custom SVGs or only default QGIS symbologies ?

Maybe try to use *Embedded Symbols* so that the SVG file follows the layer with no need to keep a constant path to the original SVG file.
[image: Sorry for the picture taken on a french version of QGIS.]

Comment: Worked Thank you